# Use of word "the" with "based on" and "noun + of + noun"

Tags: word-usage, articles, prepositions

In the phrase:

"based on the conversion process of modal distances",

I understand that it is not necessary to use "the" after "based on", but also that it is usual to put "the" before the structure "noun of noun", as in "the conversion process of modal distances". Should I put "the" here or not?

Thanks

Comment: The presence or absence of "the" (or "a") after "based on" would almost certainly be determined by the usual rules for using articles.  There is nothing special about "based on" vs any other legitimate word sequence here.  [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=based+on%2Cbased+on+the%2C+based+on+a&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbased%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbased%20on%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbased%20on%20a%3B%2Cc0).

Answer (score 0):

Where did you learn that it is not usual to use "the" after "based on"? In literature and in common speech, I have always heard the definite article after "based on". I would definitely keep "the" in this case, because without it, it sounds like "conversion process" is a specific noun or proper noun. It is neither.

Comment: Actually, I have always put "the" after "based on", but after some time got in doubt if it would be really necessary, after seeing some corrections eliminating it. I expressed myself wrong: should have put only "not necessary". Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @Fabíola - You should not **always** put "the" after "based on" -- it depends **entirely** on what follows.  Eg, one might easily say "based on other considerations" or "based on current practices".  The same rules for using articles ahead of nouns apply after "based on" as apply anywhere else.

Comment: In these cases, I don't use "the". Maybe a better question would be when **not** to put "the"; I think my text sometimes has too much "the's" when compared to a native speaker one.

Answer (score 0):

For the structure

> ... based on {article} {subject} ...

Use of an article after the phrase "based on" does not depend on the phrase "based on" but on the ensuing {subject}.

The structure should be

> ... based on {{focuser} {subject}}

Where {focuser} helps to focus the subject. It may be an article, or pronoun, or adjective, or blank:

- I made the decision based on Harry's input.
- I made the decision based on the fact that the world is ending in 2 minutes.
- My love for him is based on our mutual respect for each other.
- My reaction to the situation was based on a shadow of paranoia.
- Her thesis was based on distillation processing of sweet petroleum.
- The news article was based on the frequent occurrences of school shootings.
- The video was based on frequent burglary of banks situated on lonely strips.

Whether to use an article or not, depends on the generalization of the ensuing {subject}.

The focus of a subject sits on the continuum of two extremes.

- on one extreme, totally generalized, indefinite and non-finite.

  - The idea was based on {houses burning at night}.
- on the other extreme, being focused down to a specified instance.

  - The idea was based on the {house which was burned down last week}.
  - The picture was based on John's {house which was burned down last week}.
- or somewhere in between on the continuum

  - I love listening to stories of {a woman making it to the head of an organization}.
  - I'm annoyed with {sounds} of {his making out} with {women} {at night}.
  - I'm annoyed with {the sounds} of {his making out} with {women} {at night}.
  - I'm annoyed with {sounds} of {his making out} with {those women} {at night}.
  - I was annoyed with {sounds} of {his making out} with {those women} {last night}.
  - I get annoyed with {sounds} of {men making out} with {an unknown woman} {last night}.
  - I get annoyed with {sounds} of {men making out} with {an unknown woman} in {the night}.

The phrase "based on" should not even enter the picture (except to set the context) in deciding what {focuser}, if any, the {subject} might need.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you could document the basis of your understanding.  The google reports 1.5B hits for the phrase "based on" and 1.4B for "based on the".  So 90% of the time, I would expect the article to follow the preposition.  Of course, this is a crude method, with too many results to cull false drops.

Whether to put the definite article in front of "noun on noun" constructions depends on whether those name general things or specific things.  The latter would include references to a *previous mention*.  For instance

> We measured *modal distances* using standard matrix techniques, and we drew our conclusions based on the conversion process of **the** modal distances".

It's just not any modal distances you're talking about in the second clause, but the very ones mentioned previously that were measured with matrices.  So the definite article would be appropriate.

Comment: Although I didn't downvote your answer: You are talking about the wrong _the_. The OP asked about the usage of _the_ after _based on_ and not between the two nouns.

Comment: @jera Thank you for your comment, which confuses me a bit.   The OP claimed an "understanding" that the article is not necessary after "based on."  I think that's wrong:  a native speaker wouldn't say, "based on conversion process", and that's what my first paragraph is about.  The OP also says that it's "usual" to put the article *in* the structure of "noun of noun."  I interpreted *in* to mean within the phrase, and I think the OP is wrong about that as well.

Comment: @jera Let me add that I don't mind people downvoting an answer of mine that's wrong or inapt.  I'm wrong all the time; it's the human condition.  My object is to *driveby* downvotes, those that don't leave an explanation like yours.  It's hard to correct or improve answers without some guidance, and it can leave the impression that a correct (if inapt) answer is wrong.

Comment: Why are you talking about "the modal distances" when the question is about "based on the conversion process"?

Comment: @HotLicks The OP has advanced his understanding of the placement of an article both before and "in" the "noun of noun" construction.  I think his understanding is incorrect on both counts.  If I have misinterpreted "in", then the OP can tell me without penalty.

Comment: I meant the article before the structure "noun of noun", as the Collins dictionary suggests: "You use the at the beginning of a noun group when the first noun is followed by an "of" phrase or a clause which identifies the person or thing. E.g.: There has been a slight increase in the consumption of meat." This seems to be _always_.
But it was good to read about the article "the" within "noun of the noun" because sometimes I think if having two "the's" so close is good writing or not.

Comment: @Fabíola I don't think it's always.  Google ""increase in consumption of meat" and you'll find a respectable number of hits, although "the consumption" has more.  Both sound fine to me.  I would say "increase in heart disease of the young," but not "increase in the heart disease."  In any case, I hope my answer helped more than it hurt.

Comment: May I ask something strongly related to your answer? I don't know if it's proper to write here or start a new topic. In the sentence: "Finally, the transformation matrices are discussed to obtain (...)", I haven't mentioned the term _transformation matrices_ in the text yet, but I think it's quite specific and should have _the_ before, am I right?

Comment: @Fabíola It's  hard to tell without more context, but if you use *the* without mentioning or defining them, your reader is likely to wonder what he missed.  You could say something like, "Finally, the transformation matrices used in the calculations are discussed to obtain...."

Comment: This is a summary of what is going next. I choose not to put _the_ then. Later, when I discuss it, I use "(...) using transformation matrices." without _the_. Does this sound right?

Comment: @Fabíola I'm sorry, but I can't tell without reading your paragraph.  If you like to take the discussion to chat, I'd be happy to take a look.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34657/discussion-between-fabiola-and-deadrat).